# free -g with sed -n plus nth character

Tags: linux, awk, sed, centos7, free

I am trying to create a script to display just one of the numbers from the free command. 
In my case, the number I want is on the 2nd line of the free -g output and at character slot 43. 
The original output of free -g is:

```
              total       used       free     shared buff/cache  available
Mem:              3          0          2          0          0          2     
Swap:             3          0          3
```

So far I have gotten the 2nd line to display with:

```
free -g | sed -n 2p
Mem:              3          0          2          0          0          2
```

I need just the 43rd character of that line or the 4th column?
I have looked into printf and cut but get a grody syntax error.

Comment: `awk '/MemFree:/ {printf("%d",$2/1024/1024)}' /proc/meminfo`?

Comment: we are asked to take the info out of the free -g command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a line contains `Mem:` print from this line column 4:

```
free -g | awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}'
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Do you know a decent place to find how this works?
I understand while reading what the above code does but often times do not know when or where to use different possible codes.